Mosaico usando letras solamente y la sentencia 'for' en python
El ejercicio sería:

Dado su tamaño, muestre por pantalla un mosaico donde la diagonal principal esté representada por 'X', la parte inferior por 'D' y la parte superior por 'U'.
Ejemplo:
Entrada : 5
Salida:

X  U  U  U  U

D  X  U  U  U

D  D  X  U  U

D  D  D  X  U

D  D  D  D  X

Este es el código que he hecho pero no sé cómo unirlos, o si no es así como se hace...:
num = int(input('Escriba un número cualquiera: '))

for i in range(num):

    print((i * 'D ') + (1 * 'X'))

for j in range(num - 1, -1, -1):

    print((i * 'D ') + (1 * 'X') + (j * ' U'))


¿Se te ocurrió usar matrices?

Es más: si hacés un mínimo ajuste al primer for, el segundo for pasa a ser innecesario...

Aún no he llegado a la parte de las matrices..., voy a revisar el primer for como me has dicho a ver si lo consigo. Gracias.

Te voy a dar unos "tips" para este tipo de tareas:

Siempre que veas un cuadrado, grilla o matriz, lo más probable es que debas utilizar 2 for anidados
En los programas de consola, donde vas escribiendo el resultado, debes agregar un salto de línea al terminar el segundo for (por fuera de él), así formas los cuadrados:

Ejemplo, imprimir un cuadrado solo con X
num = int(input('Escriba un número cualquiera: '))
for i in range(num):
    for j in range(num):
        print('X', end=" ") #Imprimimos SIN salto de línea (una fila)
    print("") #Imprimimos un salto de linea, para pasar a la siguiente fila

Resultado
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X

Ahora que ya sabemos imprimir un cuadrado, vamos con las condiciones (que luego se convierten en if). Para esto ya hay que analizar el problema, que para simplificarlo lo haré de 3x3
Piensa que cada casilla de la matriz tiene una coordenada (i,j), entonces la matriz es:
(0,0)  (0,1)  (0,2)
(1,0)  (1,1)  (1,2)
(2,0)  (2,1)  (2,2)

Notarás que:

La diagonal viene dada cuando i y j son iguales
El triángulo superior, viene dado cuando i es menor que j
El triángulo inferior cuando i es mayor que j

Y con esto tenemos 3 condiciones necesarias para resolver el problema, las cuales debemos agregarlas en el for interno:
num = int(input('Escriba un número cualquiera: '))

for i in range(num):
    for j in range(num):
        if j == i:
            print('X', end=" ")
        elif j>i:
            print('U', end=" ")
        else:
            print('D', end=" ")
    print("")


La anterior solución sería la manera en que se resuelve para casi cualquier lenguaje por que la característica de print(33 * 'a') no es muy común en otros lenguajes
Como tú lo estabas haciendo casi lo tenías, pero te sobra el primer for
Tu estas imprimiendo fila a fila, en cada fila separas:

La izquierda D
El centro X
La derecha U

El truco en este caso, viene dado por:

A la izquierda hay i valores
Al centro hay un único valor (la X)
A la derecha hay (aqui el truco) num-i-1 valores U

Ya que
i + 1 + (num-i-1) es igual a num, siendo num el tamaño de un lado del cuadrado, entonces
num = int(input('Escriba un número cualquiera: '))
for i in range(num):
    print((i * 'D ') + (1 * 'X') + ((num-i-1) * ' U'))


Muy útil!! Estaba obcecado en usar solo la sentencia 'for' , y así resulta mucho más práctico!! Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

@Gaspar Un gusto haber podido ayudarte. Tu casi lo tenías resuelto!!!! Acabo de incluir otra solución basado en la lógica que tu estabas implementando

En base a la edición: justamente a eso iba con que podía resolverse con un solo for.

@padaleiana, la única opción que se me pasó probar y probé de todas las maneras, jeje, muchas gracias por la ayuda, estoy comenzando a aprender programación y aún me queda mucho por aprender y practicar!!

@Gaspar enfocate en también trabajar la lógica. Luego, llevarlo a un lenguaje de programación te será un poco más sencillo.
